# visual studio weird behavior

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, winapi, dialog

I am making a win32 application using visual studio 2008.

When ever i compile my code which generates a simple dialog, all of the dialogs text show in Chinese language. I have not set Chinese anywhere. can some one elaborate what the issue is?

My code is

```
#include <windows.h>

int WINAPI WinMain(
    HINSTANCE   nowInstance,
    HINSTANCE   prevInstance,
    LPSTR   ipCmdLine,
    int     nCmdShow
    )
{
    MessageBox(NULL,"My First Program","Our University",MB_OK); 

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: There are no dialogs or Chinese shown here. Can you elaborate on what the issue is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you're mixing Unicode and ANSI.

Have you tried

```
MessageBox(NULL, _T("My First Program"), _T("Our University"), MB_OK);
```

And does that give you the expected results?

Comment: You were compiled with _UNICODE set, so Windows expected all strings to be in UTF16 format, and you gave them ASCII.  It's a lot like giving a float to a function expecting an int, except there's no compiler warning.

Comment: @backTangent: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html "The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)"

Comment: @Mooing Defining `_UNICODE` makes Windows expect strings to contain two-byte fixed width characters which is not UTF-16.  The distinction is inconsequential most of the time because they are the same for most of the codepoints you'll encounter (see BMP - Basic Multilingual Plane)

Comment: @IronMensan: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4592261/windows-api-ansi-and-wide-character-strings-is-it-utf8-or-ascii-utf-16-or-uc says as of Windows 2000 they accept UTF-16.  However, it also says that filepaths are opaque arrays, except for uppercase/lowercase, which means the "equivalent" characters may not be treated as equivalent.