# Why are there two functions with the same name, but followed with 'A' and 'W' in .dll files?

Tags: dll, kernel32

Sorry about the really bad title, but this is difficult to explain and hopefully someone can clear this up for me.

I am using a tool called dllexp(1) to view the functions in some common .dll files(kernel32, user32, etc)

[image]

Why are there versions with 'A' and versions with 'W'. What is the difference here?

Thanks

1. http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/dll_export_viewer.html

Comment: "ANSI", "WIDE" - ref. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4592261/windows-api-ansi-and-wide-character-strings-is-it-utf8-or-ascii-utf-16-or-u (also note the signature change: LPCSTR for A, LPWSTR/LPCWSTR for W.)

Comment: These are functions that take string arguments.  30+ years ago everybody wrote strings in English.  20 years ago Microsoft noted that not everybody speaks English on this planet.  And decided to support Unicode.  W = wide = unicode, A = ansi = 8-bit characters.  Two functions to get the same job done, makes everybody happy.

Comment: For some definitions of "unicode" anyway :)