# Why no Java Charset setEncoding method?

Tags: java, character-encoding

I found [this excellent SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2281646/whats-the-difference-between-encoding-and-charset) asking for the distinction between a character *set* vs. character *encoding*. And it makes sense: essentially the character set is the set of glyphs available for use, and its respective encoding is how each glyph translates to and from binary.

I then went to the [Java 7 SE `Charset` API doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/charset/Charset.html) and was surprised only to see a `getEncoding()` method but no respective *setter*. So it seems that, at least in Java land, every character set gets "bound" to a pre-configured encoding.

This got me thinking: **why is there no setter here?** Why does Java not allow the user to define what encoding to use for binding a set of characters to binary?

Along those same lines, what if Java doesn't support a particular character set/encoding? Is there a way to extend the JRE with custom sets/encodings?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because what Java calls a Charset is what you call an encoding. The documentation of CharSet describes a Charset as:

> A named mapping between sequences of sixteen-bit Unicode code units and sequences of bytes.

BTW, there is no `getEncoding()` method in Charset.

Comment: Thanks @JB Nizet (+1) - so how do you specify which `Charset` (encoding) and which (actual) character set to use for a given application?

Comment: All characters in Java are unicode, and you can use whatever character in this gigantic set of characters you want. You don't have to choose any set of characters when dealing with characters. When you transform these characters to bytes, that's where you'd better choose a charset (or encoding, if you prefer) that supports the characters you want to write. UTF-8 is generally a good choice (at least in western countries), because it supports every unicode character, and uses only 1 byte for the most frequent western characters.

Answer (score 1):

For the question:

> Along those same lines, what if Java doesn't support a particular
>   character set/encoding? Is there a way to extend the JRE with custom
>   sets/encodings?

Java has support for pretty much any encoding you might want: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/intl/encoding.doc.html