# Arabic not saving in oracle database

Tags: java, json, oracle, arabic

We are receiving Json payload from API, e.g.

```json
{
"customerName": "علي الدويش",
"customerCode": "999999",
"shipAddress1": "البلاغة", 
}
```

We are using Spring Boot to save it in object `jsonObjectPayload`

```java
String payloadStr = mapper.readTree(jsonObjectPayload).toPrettyString();
queue.setPayload(new String(payloadStr.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8), StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
```

While saving it in Oracle column with `CLOB` data type

Output:
we are getting value as :

```json
{
"customerName" : "��� ������",
"shipAddress1" : "�������",
}
```

We are using Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production
with `NLS_CHARACTERSET  AR8MSWIN1256`.

In UAT environment we have `NLS_CHARACTERSET    AL32UTF8` and the value are reflecting Arabic one
Is this issue related to NLS_CHARACTERSET ?? as both support arabic encoding.

We also try `queue.setPayload(new String(payloadStr.getBytes("8859_1"), "UTF-8"));` in java but no difference occur same ????? garbage value are there
Code to save data in DB

```
public void insertOrderInvoiceInQueue(OrderInvoiceQueueDTO invoice) 
{
String sql = "INSERT INTO AMG_OIP_ORDER_INVOICE_QUEUE (PAYLOAD) VALUES (:payload)";
SqlParameterSource parameters = new MapSqlParameterSource()
                .addValue("payload", invoice.getPayload())
            
logger.info("Saving invoice AMG_OIP_ORDER_INVOICE_QUEUE table.");
        xcenterjdbcTemplate.update(sql, parameters);
        logger.info("Saved...");
    }
```

Comment: Why do you have to convert String to ByteArray & back to String?  Can't you just use the original string itself? `new String(payloadStr.getBytes("8859_1"), "UTF-8")` - I am talking about this. Why can't you use `queue.setPayload(payloadStr)`?

Comment: Yeah your string fiddling is completely [wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39308860/2541560).

Comment: I agree with Ishan.  Remove all use of bytes and Charsets.  At best, it is pointless.  Also, please edit your question and show us your code which saves information to the database.

Comment: Also, if you just use the original string as-is and save it in DB, did you check in the DB directly to see if the data is stored correctly?  Garbage characters showing up in Console or Log might just be an issue of that display/Log not supporting unicode properly. The data stored in the DB might be correct. Did you use SQL Developer to see the data in the DB?

Comment: @Ishan I am willing to try your solution but the only problem is that this issue occur only in  production  not in UAT DB.

Comment: That is strange. Then something is different in the PROD environment configuration. Check JDBC and other configuration parameters. See what are the differences between UAT and PROD.

Comment: @Ishan As I mention above the only difference is the NLS_CHARACTERSET of PROD and UAT. So can I assume the Code has no issue ? Only issue with DB NLS_CHARACTERSET

Comment: Yes, that is a possibility. Try to change in UAT to make it same as PROD, and see if in UAT the same issue is reproduced. Change it again and see if it is gone. If that works, then do the same in PROD

Answer (score 0):

Earlier the table column has `CLOB` data type that hold the payload of Arabic language. Now I change it with `NCLOB` data type as it uses 2 or 3 bytes per character to store characters in the Unicode character set. Now Arabic characters are stored in database.