# Unicode and UTF-8 difference, lof of inconsistencies from the whole internet

Tags: encoding, character-encoding

I know there are a lot of answers about this subject, but I need some clarification.

From what I've understood, ASCII and Unicode are both **charsets**,
they tell you that A is decimal(41) and B is decimal(42) for example.

UTF-8, UTF-16, UTF-32, and ANSI are **encodings**
they are tasked with storing those 41 and 42 numbers into a binary form of their liking and managing their retrieval and conversion back to decimal. Then with the charset, you are able to get the corresponding char.

But, I was looking into how to get which charset/encoding is used by a webpage and I did tools>page information on Firefox.

And I can read this: charset=utf-8

(this is the page: http://www.leboncoin.fr/annonces/offres/ile_de_france/)

Is this a bug in Firefox?
Or, did I completely misunderstand charset/encoding?

Answer (score 0):

You have slightly misunderstood character sets, though this is not a big issue. A character set is just the set of available characters, it doesn't have to reference any numbers (though they almost always do). See also: [What's the difference between encoding and charset?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2281646/1607043)

The real issue here is the use of `charset`. It comes from an HTML5 meta tag that often looks something like this:

```html
<meta charset="utf-8" />
```

Despite the name, `charset` actually [specifies a character encoding](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/document-metadata.html#attr-meta-charset) in HTML5, not a character set. This is likely due to historical confusion between character sets and encodings, as there was not much difference between the two before Unicode introduced multiple encodings for a single character set.