# Encoding in python 2.7, from IDE to string

Tags: python, python-2.7, unicode, encoding, utf-8

So here I am, I read about encoding all day, now I need some clarification.

First off I'm using eclipse mars with pydev.

Unicode is a (character set + code points), basicaly a table of symbols associated with numerical value.
The way those value are going to be stored at a binary level are defined by the encoding, let's say UTF-8.

```
1 : shebang
```

What is the shebang for? when I put `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` does it do something? or does it just indicate that my file is encoded in UTF-8 (but since it's just an indication it could be a lie :o)

```
2 : Eclipse file encoding
```

After I wrote my shebang and saved I went into the property of the file, and it said encoding : ISO-8859-1, so my guess is that the shebang does nothing beside indicate in which encoding my file is.
Do I need to manually set every files to UTF-8 or is there a way to teach eclipse to read the shebang and act accordingly.

```
3 : Why does the shebang only specify the encoding?
```

My shebang say utf-8, ok right, so what? it does not tell me which caracter set is used.
Since UTF-8 is just an encoding I could use UTF-8 with any character set no?
I could encode ASCII in UTF-8 if I wanted, since an encoding is just a way to convert and store/read code points.
What if my character set encoded in utf-8 does not have the same code points than unicode? (is this possible?)

```
4 : maybe a solution?
```

I oftenly read that utf-8 is an implementation of unicode, does that mean that each times you read encoding = UTF-8 you can be 100%, and I say 100%, sure that the characterset+code points is unicode?

I'm lost

Comment: Script description line add is not the answer.
Modules between the encoding is undefined.
Python automatically gets the encoding of the current system.
Your system has to be in utf-8 encoding.
Set your os parameter as utf-8 coding system.
Python gets the information from local encoding each time it runs.
If you want to work with UTF-8, Unicode won't do you any good.

Comment: please, limit your questions to a single issue per question

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple misconceptions in your question.

[Unicode is a standard](http://www.unicode.org/standard/WhatIsUnicode.html) that is commonly used for working with text. It is not *"character set + code points"* e.g., Unicode standard defines [how to find word boundaries](http://unicode.org/reports/tr29/) or [how to compare Unicode string](http://unicode.org/reports/tr10/).

`# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` is an encoding declaration. It is not a shebang. Shebang (as it name suggests) starts with `#!` e.g., `#! /usr/bin/env python`.

You might need the encoding declaration if there are non-ascii *literal* characters in your Python *source code* e.g., you don't need an encoding declaration if you write:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2
print u"\N{SNOWMAN}"
```

But you need it if you use *literal* non-ascii characters:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
print u"☃"
```

Both scripts produce the same output *if the second script is saved using utf-8 encoding*. The encoding declaration says how to interpret bytes that constitute the Python source code to get the program text.

*"is there a way to teach eclipse to read the <strike>shebang</strike> encoding declaration and act accordingly."* is a good *separate* question. If IDE has explicit Python support then it should do it automatically.

> My <strike>shebang</strike> encoding declaration say utf-8, ok right, so what? it does not tell me which character set is used.

*"character encoding", codepage, and charset may be used interchangeably* in many contexts. See [What's the difference between encoding and charset?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2281646/4279) The distinctions are irrelevant for the task of converting from bytes to text and back in Python:

```
unicode_text = bytestring.decode(character_encoding)
bytestring = unicode_text.encode(character_encoding)
```

A bytestring is an immutable sequence of bytes in Python (roughly speaking numbers in `0..255` range) that is used to represent arbitrary binary data e.g., images, zip-archives, encrypted data, and text encoded using some character encoding. A Unicode string is an immutable sequence of Unicode codepoints (roughly speaking, numbers in `0..sys.maxunicode` range) that is used to represent text in Python.

Some character encodings such as `cp437` support only a few Unicode characters. Others such as `utf-8` support the full range of Unicode codepoints.

Answer (score 0):

The right way to add the encoding declaration is > `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-`
It tells python to change the encoding in the current script to UTF-8 it has nothing to do with the user .

Comment: That's what I meant, I wrote my question too fast (I will edit).

So the python interpreter will read the script as utf-8, so I DO HAVE to set utf-8 in my IDE properties, otherwhise python will try to read utf-8 in a file encoded in something else

Answer (score 0):

Ok I think I found an awnser to all those questions

1/
thanks to J.Dev, the shebang only tells the python interpreter in what the file is encoded, but **YOU** have to encode the file in what you put in the shebang

2/
Apparently I have to do it manually

3/
Because an encoding is associated with a charset, if you say encoding=utf-8 then it will always be a unicode charset

Some old 1 byte charset don't have encoding, you don't need encoding since the char are all stored on 1 byte, the natural binary translation is the encoding.

So when you say ASCII for instance you mean the charset and encoding = ASCII

But this leave me wondering, is there other type of charset out there with multiple encoding implementation (like unicode can be encoded in utf-8/16/32)