# how to convert ascii and extended ascii to int in c

Tags: c, ascii

Is there a way to have the decimal value (in int) of ASCII / extended ASCII characters in C (especially the extended ones)

ASCII & extended ASCII table : http://www.theasciicode.com.ar/

Example of my problem with some code :

```
int a = (int) 'a';
int b = (int) '│';

printf("%i\n", a);
printf("%i\n", b);
```

and the output is :

```
97
14849154
```

in the ASCII table, "│" is normally 179.

Comment: FYI, `(int) 'a'` is reduntant. `'a'` is already an integer.

Comment: [Extended ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_ASCII#Character_set_confusion) isn't _one_ character set so it's not a very useful term.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OP' platform is using implementation defined behavior concerning *string literals* outside the basic coding set.

UTF-8 encoding.  The `'│'` is a Unicode character [U+2502](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2502/index.htm)

When coded as a UTF-8, it has the 3-byte sequence 0xE2 0x94 0x82 or in big endian order: 0xE29482 which is 14849154 (decimal) as printed out by OP.

```
 int b = (int) '│';
```

Note: [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) is only defined for codes 0 to 127.

Comment: Yes, but you still have to wonder what the source charset actually is, what the compiler is being told it is (and what the compiler is being told to use as the execution charset). It is possible that they are all intentionally UTF-8. It is also possible that the actual source charset is UTF-8 but the compiler is being told differently. Overall, it seems like UTF-8 is a mistake in this project.

Comment: @tom Concerning "the actual source charset is UTF-8",  [What's the difference between encoding and charset?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2281646/2410359) may be useful.  I would say [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) is an encoding and not a [charset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encoding).

Comment: Agreed but charset is the term used in various compiler arguments for encoding.