# nodejs - differences between encoding on Buffer, File, String , reading and writing

Tags: node.js, encoding

I would like to check if my sistem is able to handle file given by my customers.
Due my customers can give me files in unknown encoding, i would like to create some test file in order to understand if file can be read without corruption.

my sistem run on nodejs 12.x

i read

- [this thread about encoding and charset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2281646/whats-the-difference-between-encoding-and-charset)
- [this nodejs official documentation about buffers](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_buffers_and_character_encodings)

i'm not able to understand well the differences between using encoding on writeFile

```
fs.writeFileSync("ascii.xml", Buffer.from("hello"), {'encoding':'ascii'})
```

encoding on toString

```
fs.writeFileSync("ascii.xml", Buffer.from("hello").toString(encoding="ascii"))
```

encoding on toString and also on File

```
fs.writeFileSync("ascii.xml", Buffer.from("hello").toString(encoding="ascii"), {'encoding':'ascii'})
```

encoding on Buffer and so on

```
fs.writeFileSync("ascii.xml", Buffer.from("hello",'ascii').toString(encoding="ascii"), {'encoding':'ascii'})
```

for example i'm not able to understand why this code

```
fs.writeFileSync("base64.xml", Buffer.from("string",'utf8').toString(encoding="base64"),{'encoding':'base64'})
```

produce a file containing the word "string"

but this

```
fs.writeFileSync("base64.xml", Buffer.from("string",'utf8').toString(encoding="base64"))
```

produce a file containing the base64 rappresentation of the word "string" : a base64 encoded file of a base64 encoded string generated from a base64 buffer built same character i put in the string?

thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's get the basics:

- When you call `Buffer.from("hello")`, you map (encode) the string `hello` into bytes.
  (Note that `hello` is interpreted as a UTF8 encoded string by default, so that the above expression is equivalent to `Buffer.from("hello", "utf8")`).
  The resultant buffer is:
  `<Buffer 68 65 6c 6c 6f>`.
- When you call `Buffer.from("hello").toString()`, you map (encode) `hello` into bytes, and then map (decode) those bytes back into a string.
  Again, note that UTF8 is the default, so the above expression is equivalent to `Buffer.from("hello").toString("utf8")` as well as to `Buffer.from("hello", "utf8").toString("utf8")`.
  The resultant string is unsurprisingly:
  `"hello"`.
  However, change it to `Buffer.from("hello").toString("base64")`, and you'll get:
  `aGVsbG8=`.

Now, let's move forward to `fs.writeFileSync`:

- [`fs.writeFileSync(file, data[, options])`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefilesync_file_data_options) writes a file, that is: bytes. In other words, when `data` is a string, `writeFileSync` maps (encodes) that string into bytes, and then writes those bytes into the file.
  Again, the default encoding is UTF8, but when you pass some other encoding, `data` will be mapped (encoded) into bytes using this encoding.
  By the way, when you "open the file", be it using some text editor or even the debugger itself, you probably do it (without knowing) using UTF8 encoding.

Hopefully, You can now understand that:

- `fs.writeFileSync("myFile.xml", Buffer.from("hello","utf8").toString("base64"))` maps (encodes) `hello` into bytes (using UTF8 encoding), and then maps (decodes) those bytes into a string (using Base64 encoding), which is `aGVsbG8=`.
  This is what you see when you open the file created in your *last* snippet.
- `fs.writeFileSync("myFile.xml", Buffer.from("hello","utf8").toString("base64"), "base64")` maps (encodes) `hello` into bytes (using UTF8 encoding), then maps (decodes) those bytes into a string (using Base64 encoding), then maps (encodes) this string into bytes (using Base64 encoding). This is what you do in your *penultimate* snippet.

  To illustrate, note that this series of "mappings" is equivalent to:

  ```
  var bytes = Buffer.from(Buffer.from("hello").toString("base64"), "base64")
  ```

  Which gives:
  `<Buffer 68 65 6c 6c 6f>`.

  Then, when you open the file, you (i.e., probably your text editor) read those bytes as UTF8 by default, which is equivalent to:

  ```
  bytes.toString()  // 'bytes' is defined above
  ```

  Which gives:
  `"hello"`.